How to identify a customer in a M2M client credentials flow (custom mapping)
I have a traditional .NET MVC Framework with the default Identity configuration (EntityFramework)
We have a standard login with email/password, and every user belongs to a customer, where both are a table in our database
public class Employee : IdentityUser {
    int Id;
    int CustomerId;
}

public class Customer {
    int Id;
    List<Employee> employees;
}

When they login, we add customerId as a custom claim. This works fine for a standard user login identity.
We are in the process of developing a new .NET API that needs access to the database and has to support an M2M client credentials flow, so
that third-party clients of our customers can synchronize data between their system and ours.
I am having some issues on how to identify the customerId for the particular client in this authentication flow.Since the CustomerId is in our database, and separate from the authorization flow, whether it be Azure AD/Microsoftn Entra, Auth0 (these are the main 2 I've looked at).
The way I see it, there are two conceptual ways of solving this.

We can add customerId as a custom claim in the authentication service we will be using. 
Azure AD does not seem to support this. They only have a defined set of custom claims that can be used. Auth0 does
seem to support this through Auth0 actions, but it means that we would have to manually add the customerId in the Auth0 Dashboard for each integration.

We have some sort of mapping in our database with the different clientIds and their respective CustomerId. 
This would work fine with either Azure AD or Auth0, since the customerId is resolved in our own code based on the clientId. Therefore, when the user creates an integration with our system, we use either an Auth0 Dashboard API or a Microsoft Graph API (?) to create clientId and clientSecret, which we then provide to the user. We would also store the clientId in our database, so we know which Customer it belongs to. Then, when they call our API, we implement some sort of middleware which resolves the customerId based on a lookup in our database given the clientId.


I was just hoping for some input on this. Are there any other options?
What are the industry standards (if any) for this problem? Which solution is the best/most scalable?

I can say that the default identity + AAD as external auth provider will make the app to create a corresponding account in database and mapping the microsoft account with the local account. We have a tutorial here, and after I test the external sign-in, there will be one more user account add into the database table. Therefore, I recommend setting up reflection relationship.
